# Window manufacturer

Tags: windows

[image]

I’m not able to find my window company

Comment: Because that is the certification label, not the manufacturers info tag.

Answer (score 3):

Plugging GLW-CO-101 or GLW-CO-102 into a well-known search engine indicates that these are likely from Great Lakes Window, Inc.